# 1 ViewController per view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I wanted to know if I have to create a new ViewController for each view I have. Let's say I have 3 views do I need 3 viewControllers or does 1 ViewController can manage all 3 views?

Edit: Views are Objects that I create with .xib file so following the description given me by Xcode 4.3.3: represents a rectangular region in which it draws and receive events.
My situation : What I want is the main View showing 3 buttons, each button leads to a new View. That's about it each of the 3 views will have about the same thing, a tableView to display data parsed from an XML.

Thanks again!

EndEdit

Thanks

Comment: Each ViewController should just manage one root view. One ViewController can absolutely have a root view with three subviews and manage that hierarchy itself.

Comment: @Ben, you should probably clarify if you mean instances of UIView or views as in "screens" or "scenes".

Comment: @DrummerB "screen" or "scene" are not part of the iOS terminology, hence using them in a "clarification" would not add value to the comment - which btw is entirely correct.

Comment: Well judging by the answers so far it's not so clear. What would you call it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your situation and what you want to present to the user. If those 3 view controllers have very similar functions and only minor differences, then you could use the same class and have an instance variable to indicate which mode you're in. For instance if you have a list of Songs, Playlists or Videos, those could be the same class, with an enum variable to differentiate between the 3 modes. If your views are significantly different however (like a Song list and a Video player) then you should usually have separate classes for them.

Answer (score 3):

Both are possible, depends on your needs. View controllers can easily manage more than one (sub)view (e.g. every UI control subclasses UIView and you can have many in a single view controller). Sometimes it's more convenient to put views in different view controllers, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS, general best practice has been for a single view controller to manage a single "screen (or "window", but of course there is only one of these on an iOS device). This view controller may support a variable number of view objects (certainly not a ratio of 1:1 views/view controller).

As of iOS 5, nesting multiple view controllers managing multiple views in single window is now technically supported, but I still consider it a practice best avoided.

One window = one view controller = multiple views.

Answer (score 1):

In one view controller you can manage any number of views.

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to use a viewcontroller per view. the advantages of the approch is as follows:

1. Any time you can convert the Template of the application. (eg. from table view to tabview or split view can make quick change)
2. with each view controller you follow the MVC architecture.
3. if you have n controller than try to manage n MVC model so that you can shift any model any where easily.
4. Memory management will be easy (Push and Pop manage memory automatically.)
5. if we have sigle view controller and n number of view than it will be quite difficult to manage memory.
   Also we need to keep the screen ID for each view and need to mantain also their switching.

there are  N number of advantages if you use N numbers of viewcontroller over N number of views.

Comment: However on iOS you often have views very similar to each other. If you have a couple of views that are 90% the same and the rest is different, you would have a lot of redundant code.

Comment: then make some function which can change GUI. and ultimatly take three  member variable of same view controller so it is ultimatly 3 views with there own controllers.

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: it make sense please think about it.